# Extract json files from gradle runtime dependency jars

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I need to go over the list of `runtime dependencies` and from the jars i need to extract the `json` files in folders with respective `jar name`.

I have tried the below code, but it creates a folder of the name of the last jar it reads and puts all `json` files inside it maintaining the path from the `jar root`.

```
task copyJsonToQrelease(type: Copy) {
    configurations.runtime.each { File f ->
        from zipTree(f)
        include "**/*.json"
        into "${viewRoot}/Qrelease/JsonResources/"+f.getName()
        includeEmptyDirs = false
    }
}
```

> **result** : Qrelease\JsonResources\netty-common-4.1.16.Final.jar\release resources\DummyService.json
>
> **expected result**: Qrelease\JsonResources\MyJarName\DummyService.json

Answer (score 0):

The name of the jar file is `netty-common-4.1.16.Final.jar`.

So, the `MyJarName` part should is correct, right?

The `release-resources\DymmyService.json` is the name of the json file.

Therefore, you want to [rename](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:renaming_files) the json file.

This should work for windows (not tested):

```
rename(/.*\\(.+json)/, '$1')
```

Beware - this regex is OS specific. Better: build that regex OS depended.

Comment: Actually i don't want to rename the json file, according to me the f.getName() should bring the jar name, so the path of the extracted json should be Qrelease\JsonResources\MyJarName\DummyService.json, but it is not happening.

Comment: Yes, `f.getName()` gives you the jar file name and that part is correct - as far as I understand you. 
But, you are applying a filter on a file tree and the result is a "filtered file tree" and you are copying that filtered file tree into a directory. 

The json file name in your example is `release-resources\DummyService.json`. If you don't want to rename it, .. you have to accept the result.